# How to render the form tag

Tags: theming, users

I am using this code to make the user_profile_form available on my user-profile.tpl.php so the user profile filed can be edited directly from the sure page.

```
function parce_preprocess_user_profile(&$variables) {
  $variables['user_edit']  = drupal_get_form('user_profile_form', menu_get_object('user'));
}
```

Then, I can correctly print them individually using this code:

```
<?php print drupal_render($user_edit['account']['mail']); ?>
```

It works fine, but the problem is that the `<form>` tag doesn't appear on the page, and the form doesn't submit. When I add it manually in the template page, it works, but I was wondering how to get Drupal to insert these tags automatically.

I tried something like this (out of pure guess):

```
function parce_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path){
  return array(
    'user_profile_form' => array(
      'render element' => 'profile_edit',
      'template' => 'user-profile',
    ),
  );
}
```

It doesn't work. Am I doing anything wrong?

Comment: I am not clear why you would show the edit form at every user profile page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't find a way around that; I ended up printing the form tag manually.

Answer (score 2):

You have to render the full form, so `drupal_render($user_edit)` is needed.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Daniel, but when i do that the form tag is being printed of the page but now my form elements are not within the Form Tag. Basically i end up with <form .... > </form> Then my form inputs

Comment: Still not working, when i do this the form element that i am printing end up outside the `<form>` tags